# SQL match column value from one table with column values in another without joining

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.
One is the task table
 [Task Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkBct.png)

WONumber table
[WONumber table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS0XW.png)

Now I need to look for wonumber from the wonumber table and look for the taskname in the task table.
Basically joining the two tables.

I tried this query but it doesnt work

```
select * from task at t
join wonumber as w
on t.taskname like '%'+w.wonumber+'%'
```

but this produces like 70000 rows and slows down the database and I have to restart it.
There should be a way to look for one table value in another when both tables are not related.

Comment: try using where clause you want to compare any specific ID, the result you r getting will be many: many mapping from both tables

Answer (score 1):

This is for sure bad DB design but if you are sure that `task.taskName` ends with `#***` and `wonumber.wonumber` starts with `#` then you can improve performance (a little) using

```
select * from task at t
join wonumber as w
on t.taskname like '%'+w.wonumber --no trailing '%'
```

Comment: could help him a bit

Answer (score 0):

Try this if the data pattern is guaranteed to be consistent (# followed by tasknumber in both tables) and that this pattern is at the end in the "Task" table and that there are no spaces at the end.

```
Select * from
(
Select t.*, Right(t.taskname, Patindex('%#%', t.taskname ) + 1 ) as TaskNum
From Task t
) a INNER JOIN WonNumber w 
on a.TaskNum = w.wonumber
```

BTW you are getting into these odd situations because of a poor db design that Tasknumber should be in its seperate column in both tables and this would be a simple super fast inner join query. So Iam essentially extracting the tasknumber column as a seperate column from the task table so that I can use it to join with the Wonnumber table. HTH !